# How to toggle accordion using Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get my accordion to toggle but nothing seems to be happening. By toggle I mean clicking the same accordion header should close it as well. So far I've managed to get it to work by clicking another header the previous one will close, but closing an open one and keeping them all closed seems to not be working.

here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accordion section h1").click(function(e) {
    $(this).parents().siblings("section").addClass("ac_hidden");
    $(this).parents("section").removeClass("ac_hidden");
    $(this).collapse('toggle')
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

I've tried playing the collapse outside of the function `$(#accordion).collapse('toggle'), I've tried to use`('hide')` as well but no luck.

here is a jsfiddle of it: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxyozw5c/1/)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#accordion section h1").click(function(e) {
  if (!$(this).closest('section').hasClass('ac_hidden')) {
    $(this).closest("section").addClass("ac_hidden");
  } else {
    $(this).closest("section").siblings().addClass("ac_hidden");
    $(this).closest("section").removeClass("ac_hidden");
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

I've changed `.parents()` to `.closest()` as it's a better selector for this scenario, it will grab the closest section to the clicked header which is what we want, I've then just added a check to make sure the current element doesn't have the `ac_hidden` class and if not then add it (slide the current one up) else we are sliding a different one down and the functionality is what you pretty much had already. Hope that helps.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jxyozw5c/2/)

Comment: awesome! thank you, it works perfectly in jsfiddle but for some reason (and this is common in my CMS) when I click the header it takes me to a page that says "This address is not a functioning page on our site" and then in the url it shows `#` so for some reason the anchor tag is interfering

Comment: I can't really see why preventDefault wouldn't work, are you adding any dynamic content to the page when it is loaded? If that's the case then you need to use .on('click', function(){}) instead of .click() to handle that.

Comment: On the main page yes, it pulls the funds raised dynamically, but not on the FAQs page where this going, the FAQs page is just css html and this js code. I think its just some weird issue with the CMS I use Luminate Online/Convio . It's a terrible system lol. if i use `javascript:void(0)` for the href it works fine but I feel like that's a bad thing to use in this situation.

Comment: OH! nvm sorry man I'm an idiot, I accidentally replaced the `$(document).ready(function() {` part of my code when pasting yours lol it works perfectly now thank you!

Comment: No worries, glad i could help

Answer (score 1):

This is the javascript code for the accordion on my website, benstechgarage.com/accordion.html

```
$('.accordion').on('click', '.accordion-control', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this)
        .next('.accordion-panel')
        .not(':animated')
        .slideToggle();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have to check if it have the class so you can close it 
`if( !$(this).parents("section").hasClass("ac_hidden")){
    $(this).parents().addClass("ac_hidden");
   console.log(1)
   return;
  }`

check this out:
https://jsfiddle.net/jxyozw5c/3/

Comment: thank you for your response, seems like there are a number of ways to do it. I will save this as well for notes, thanks again!